# Protection for cells in Google Sheets

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there some way to speed this up, since it keeps timing out while running?

The spreadsheet is shared with a Google Group with editing permissions. I've loaded what I can into memory but each `.addEditor` and `.removeEditor` takes up to 3 seconds each x 100s of cells.

I have the sheet deleting the first row in the spreadsheet so it always shows the current day. I need to reapply cell-location-based named protections after deleting the first row since I need to use the named protection to delete the protection when a user deletes their booking.

```
var lockedRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B3:F200");
  var lockedValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B3:F200").getValues();
   var numRows = lockedRange.getNumRows();
   var numCols = lockedRange.getNumColumns();
   for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
      if (lockedValues[i-1][j-1].indexOf("@") > -1) {
          var protection = lockedRange.getCell(i, j).protect();
          protection.addEditor(lockedValues[i-1][j-1]);
          protection.setDescription(SheetName+lockedRange.getCell(i,j).getA1Notation());
          protection.removeEditor("Google Group Email");
          lockedRange.getCell(i,j).setBackground("#d6f8ff"); 
              if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
                  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
              }  
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `var protection` should be defined outside of the `for` loops.  Put that further up top.  You are already doing that with `numRows`

Comment: please excuse my ignorance but I don't think I can define the `var protection` outside of the for loop since that specifies the exact cell whose protection I need to modify unless....can `set var protection` to a range? @sandygood

Comment: When a variable is first defined, you can assign a value to it, or leave it undefined.  You don't need to assign a value to a variable when it is first defined.  If you use:  `var protection`, the variable `protection` will be undefined.  JavaScript is constantly trying to "coerce" variables into the data type that it "thinks" that it should be.  It does that no matter where you define the variable.  By using the `var` keyword in the loop, you are causing the variable to be constantly defined.  You only need to define it once.  A variable gets reassigned on every loop, no matter what you do.